# Terramaster D5-300 Linux support

Tags: linux, raid, usb-storage

I've bought a Terramaster D5-300 storage array from Amazon to build a simple but resilient storage array. The instructions are usable but not brilliant and the provided software is for Windows or Mac. However, people say it's usable with Linux but I can't find any further information. Does this mean they are configurable with Linux or just that they can be presented when set up? Any experience would be helpful.

Comment: Terramaster D5-300 doers not require software. The RAID feature is managed by hardware in the unit itself.

Comment: Configure the device using a Windows box, then unplug the device and reconnect it to Linux. Using `lsusb` od `dmesg` you can check if the unit is known to the kernel or not. In the first case, it should appear just as a removable disk. In the second case, try a search on Google with the device ids, to find if a driver is available.

Comment: @AndrewQ that's what I had concluded. Turn that into an answer if you want ;)

Comment: @SimonGreenwood you should write an answer based on your experience when the installation ends and the unit works (or not), so we know if this unit can work on Linux (add the Linux distro you're using, please).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around to populating the device with 2Tb disks and connected it to my server. The disks are presented as five separate disk devices. After a bit of research I decided to use `btrfs` RAID10, which provides just under 4Tb of space.
I can only assume that the Windows and MacOS software is providing a graphical interface to native tools and as such is limited to RAID5 as advertised. Presumably if you know what you are doing it can be configured in different ways on Windows and MacOS as well.